# NextJs function call not accepting passed argument variable

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, shopify

I am working on a Shopify site, and currently working on getting the shopping cart functioning. I have an onClick event, that triggers a function on the page to start the cart addition. I check first to see if there is already a cartId in local storage. If there isn't, I make a call to generate a new cart. This works. I then add the returned id to local storage. I then set a local variable to act as this cartId by setting it to localStorage.getItem('cartId'). I then call the addItemToCart function. When I console.log inside that function, I would expect to see the correct cartId. However, it is getting sent over as undefined. But yet the itemId and quantity that I am passing are coming through. I have validated every which way that the local variable that I am setting from local storage is properly set. But it just refuses to pass it through.

*Function called from the onClick() event*

```js
async function addToCart(itemId, quantity) {

    console.trace();

    // Check to see if a cartId was passed through, if not send a query to create a cart before adding item
    if (localStorage.getItem('cartId') === null) {

        console.log('------------------------------')
        console.log('Creating new cart with item...')
        console.log('------------------------------')

        const shopifyResponse = await createCart();

        localStorage.setItem('checkoutUrl', shopifyResponse.checkoutUrl)
        localStorage.setItem('cartId', shopifyResponse.cartId)

    }
    let savedCartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId') 


    console.log('--------------------------------')
    console.log(`Adding items to existing cart: ID: ${savedCartId} ...`)
    console.log('--------------------------------')

      const shopifyResponse = await addItemToCart({
        itemId,
        savedCartId,
        quantity
      })
      
      console.log(shopifyResponse)
}
```

*addItemToCart function that should receive the cartId*

```js
import { postToShopify } from "./shopify";

export const addItemToCart = async ({  itemId, cartId, quantity }) => {

    console.log(`Item Id: ${itemId}`)
    console.log(`Cart Id: ${cartId}`) //Returns undefined no matter where I have the argument in the function
    console.log(`Quantity: ${quantity}`)

    try {
      const shopifyResponse = await postToShopify({
        query: `
          mutation addItemToCart($cartId: ID!, $lines: [CartLineInput!]!) {
            cartLinesAdd(cartId: $cartId, lines: $lines) {
              cart {
                id
                lines(first: 10) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      id
                      quantity
                      merchandise {
                        ... on ProductVariant {
                          id
                          title
                          priceV2 {
                            amount
                            currencyCode
                          }
                          product {
                            title
                            handle
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                estimatedCost {
                  totalAmount {
                    amount
                    currencyCode
                  }
                  subtotalAmount {
                    amount
                    currencyCode
                  }
                  totalTaxAmount {
                    amount
                    currencyCode
                  }
                  totalDutyAmount {
                    amount
                    currencyCode
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        variables: {
            cartId,
          lines: [
            {
              merchandiseId: itemId,
              quantity,
            },
          ],
        },
      });
  
      return shopifyResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addItemToCart` expects as parameter an object with the following properties: `itemId`, `cartId` and `quantity` which you are destructuring.

When you call this function in `addToCart` you are passing to it an object which has `savedCartId` property instead of `cartId`. To solve this:

```
const shopifyResponse = await addItemToCart({
  itemId,
  cartId: savedCartId,
  quantity
})
```

Comment: Oh my god.... how could I have been so blind. Thank you!!!